# Excel VBA code for creating a chart object and plotting xyscatterline with data from different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I couldn't figure out what is wrong with the VBA code I created to plot data from worsheets that satisfying a condition on their name . xyscatter line to be created using data from column G as xvalues and column J as values.

I get error "Run-time error '1004': Application - defined or object-defined error"
Help is much appreciated as I will be doing this very often.

Thank you!

```
Sub charting()
Dim i, j, last_column, last_row As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cht As Chart
Dim xrng1, yrng1 As Range
Set cht = Charts.Add
i = 0
With cht
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .Name = "cht1"
End With
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If LCase(sh.Name) Like "nov*" Or LCase(sh.Name) Like "bh*" Then
        i = i + 1
        With sh
            last_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row            
            Set xrng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(last_row, 7))
            Set yrng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(last_row, 10))
        End With
    End If
        cht.Activate
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = xrng1
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = yrng1
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: x values are cells from g2 to g10 and y values are cells from j2 to j10 for example. they are plotted to get xyscatterline. data from worksheets satisfying the condition to be plotted as each series.

Comment: That's correct. I was not attentive enough... I will delete my comment. Now, why try using `FullSeriesCollection` and not `SeriesCollection`? If I remember well it has a problem if one cell in the range is not visible...

Comment: i haven't try that before so I don't know the difference to be honest. I can give it a try. Is it  wroking for you with seriescollection?

Comment: I all the time used `FullSeriesCollection`. I remember that I also tried `FullSeriesCollection` some years before, but I could not use it. I must confess, I do not remember the reason...